# getting the right data model with dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto, nosql

I am about to create my first dynamodb table and can't find a proper solution to model my requirements. It sounds very basic, but probably my brain is still too much into relational database world.

I want to do store something similar like that:

A user can buy a product (once or several times). What I want to store is `username`, `product_id`

The only things I need to query later are:

- which products have been purchased by user `X`
- how many times were they purchased

First I considered having having an item with two attributes: `username` and `product_id`. But then I cannot use `username` as primary key (a user can buy more than once) neither can I user `username` +  `product_id` (user can buy a product several times)

Now I would go for having `username`, `product_id`, `counter` and taking `username` + `product_id` as primary key. However, I will always need to check first if a product was already purchased and update it, otherwise create a new entry. For getting all products of a user I would create a global secondary index on `username`.

However, I am not very sure if this is the right way. Any feedback would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a number of ways to do this and I don't know all of your requirements so I can't guarantee this is the right answer for you but based on your description, this is what I would do.

First, I'm assuming that each order has some sort of unique order number associated with it.  I would use this order number as the primary key of the table.  I wouldn't use a range key.  This would ensure that the constraint that all primary keys be unique is met.  In addition, when I write the data to DynamoDB I would also write the username and the product_id as additional attributes.

Next, I would create a Global Secondary Index that uses the username as the primary key and the product_id as the range key.  Unlike the primary key of the table, GSI keys do not have to be unique so if a user purchased a particular product more than once, this would be fine.  This GSI would allow me to perform queries such as "find all orders by username" or "find all orders where username purchased product_id".

If you also needed to do queries like "find all usernames who purchased product_id" you would need another GSI that used product_id as the primary key and username as the range key.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought! unfortunately there is no order ID available in my case. As my only requirements are those above, I found an even simpler way to model it: `username` as primary key and `product_ids` as a list of all product that have been purchased.

Comment: garnaat is right. If you don't have order id it is still fine. Just use username as primary key and product_id as range key.